# Redirect/overwrite resource request without changing actual file URL in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

In CefSharp, I need to redirect all resource/file requests from a domain (e.g. `fileserver.com`) to a different domain (e.g. `myfileserver.com` which will mirror the same files with sometimes a bit of modifications (like changed graphics/.png files).

I have tried implementing an `IRequestHandler` with `OnBeforeResourceLoad` which would check and redirect all resource requests going to `fileserver.com` to `myfileserver.com` instead. For example:

```cs
public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
{
    string originalUrl = request.Url;
    if (request.Url.contains("http://fileserver.com"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fileserver.com: " + request.Url);

        string filename = GetFileName(request.Url);
        // e.g. http://fileserver.com/abc.png = abc.png

        // We want to use the files from myfileserver.com instead
        request.Url = "http://myfileserver.com/" + filename;
    }

    callback.Dispose();
    return CefReturnValue.Continue;
}
```

Now, the above code should work (works using with a HTML `img` tag), the problem is that `fileserver.com` is used for a Flash game and I don't think it handles this sort of redirect correctly as it still expects to get the file from the real URL, and this causes for no files/graphics from `fileserver.com` or `myfileserver.com` to be loaded in the Flash game as the original URL got cancelled from the redirect.

So, I think I would have to do this redirect/overwrite the `fileserver.com` requested resource without doing an actual URL change.

As an alternative, I have been trying to get `IResponseFilter` with `IResponseFilter.Filter` to directly overwrite the file [bytes?] instead of redirecting. However, I'm completely lost in how to do it.

Here is some pseudocode on how I imagined it would work (I have `myfileserver.com` files now on my disk instead):

```cs
FilterStatus IResponseFilter.Filter(Stream dataIn, out long dataInRead, Stream dataOut, out long dataOutWritten)
{
    // For example, fileserver.com has requested file abc.png
    // Read bytes from my local version of the file from fileserver.com
    byte[] myLocalFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("myfileserver\\abc.png"); // name of requested file, not very sure how to retrieve this here

    // Write my file to the requested file from fileserver.com to replace it
    memoryStream.Write(myLocalFileBytes, 0, myLocalFileBytes.Length);
    // This is obviously completely wrong and probably even the wrong place, sorry!

    return FilterStatus.Done;
}
```

(I got this idea from [filter in CefSharp repo](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Filters/FindReplaceResponseFilter.cs), as I couldn't find any other methods to try overwrite file without doing URL redirect, but no clue how to make it read my local file and write it over the requested file)

My other idea is to make `myfileserver.com` pretend that it's actually `fileserver.com` but don't think it's possible.

I have no experience with trying to read/write memory like this so I have no idea what to do. I would appreciate any help or feedback, thanks.

Comment: `ResourceFilter` isn't really the best approach here. You are better off using a `ISchemeHandlerFactory`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-handling for background. Register your factory for `http` or `https` whichever is relevant, specify the `domain` so you only get requests, you can then proxy the calls to your new domain, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/73/CefSharp.Example/FlashResourceHandler.cs for an example that can be adapted.

Comment: @amaitland I implemented the `FlashResourceHandler` and it seems to work! However, is it possible to use local file instead of `WebRequest.Create` to load my version of the file. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, either modify the example I provided or use one of the static helper methods provided by the default implementation at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/71.0.0/html/Methods_T_CefSharp_ResourceHandler.htm

Comment: Start with `ResourceHandler.FromFilePath`